# Selecting text in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

I'm using PyCharm for a while, and it is a great IDE, but one thing is driving me crazy. I'm using Darcula theme, and in some windows text selection is barely visible. See screen shot below (taken from refactoring window):
[image: Refactor window selection]
`Test` is selected.

I've looked up in settings, but haven't found any option to change it. I want to all selections look like below:
[image: Search window]

Is there any way to change it without changing theme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the color of the highlight by going into the Pycharm>Preferences>Editor>Color & Fonts. Then select the highlight color which you want to change. Hope this helps.

Comment: I am using PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3 and I don't see a highlight color under Color&Fonts. What value did you change?

Comment: I found it: Color&Fonts\General\Caret row is the background of the line your cursor is on. And Color&Fonts\General\Selection background is the background of your selection

Comment: You can also change the foreground color of selected text in `Editor` > `Colors & Fonts` > `General` > `Editor` > `Selection foreground`. It helps to have the foreground be high contrast against the background.

Answer (score 1):

In PyCharm 2023.* versions, go to `Settings > Editor > Color Scheme > General`.

Then go to `Editor > Selection background` and select a bright yellow hue.